# one week information of alertlofile

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I want to view the ORA errors in alertlogfile of past 7 (monday-sunday)days,
by writting in shell scripts.
Can anybody help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
sed -n -e '/start_time/,/end_time/ {/ORA/ p}' logfile
```

or [with awk](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626+1236411861955+28353475&threadId=1270397)

```
$ start="Fri Feb 27 08:00:00 2009"
$ end="Fri Mar 6 08:00:00 2009"

$ awk -v prev="$start" -v last="$end" '$0 ~ prev,$0 ~ last' logfile
```

A more sophisticated script looking for last date entries in ORA file is [available here](http://objectmix.com/awk/26974-awk-between-two-dates.html), but also at [dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_shell_script_check_alert_log.htm)

This does not answer *exactly* your request but might give you some clues to start your own script.

Comment: Thanks 
It's working.
Am trying to display the date along with ORA errors.

Comment: Great. Feel free to complete your question with your current progress and what is missing

Answer (score 0):

I want the scripts which give output as follows (one week errors) and it should be mail to my id.

Sat Mar 14 10:30:51 IST 2009

ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 2 - see DBWR trace file

Sat Mar 12 12:35:06 IST 2009

ORA-01110: data file 2: '/u02/oradata/Globe/undotbs01.dbf'

Sat Mar 10 09:54:05 IST 2009
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status

Sat Mar 08 :15:02 IST 2009

ORA-1157 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE OPEN...

Sat Mar 07 12:35:51 IST 2009

ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 2 - see DBWR trace file